# Auto Layout - How to find out when a layout constraint is added and by who?

Tags: ios, debugging, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In IB I have set up a width/height constraints on my UIButton.  I have verified that in viewDidLoad the constraints were correct.  Somewhere along the line, a conflicting constraint was added to the button (as verified in viewWillLayoutSubviews).  How can I find out when a layout constraint is added and by who? Is there a callback that gets triggered when a constraint is added to a control/view?

In viewDidLoad:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7fb145023f90>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb140a8aec0 H:[UIButton:0x7fb145194430'X'(44)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb140a8af10 V:[UIButton:0x7fb145194430'X'(44)]>
)
```

In viewWillLayoutSubviews:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7fb140aee6c0>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb140a8aec0 H:[UIButton:0x7fb145194430'X'(44)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb140a8af10 V:[UIButton:0x7fb145194430'X'(44)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb140bd2e60 H:[UIButton:0x7fb145194430'X'(40)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb145155ea0 V:[UIButton:0x7fb145194430'X'(40)]>
)
```

Comment: You could possibly subclass UIButton and watch for a change in the button.constraints.

Comment: exactly. But the array does change. At one point it contains two constraints. At another point it contains four. So set a watch breakpoint on that array to see when it is changed.

Comment: Can you list your answer?